# Retrieving JSON data from RESTful API to Tableau

Tags: json, heroku, tableau-api

I have a RESTful API that I hosted on Heroku:

https://newsaggrarab.herokuapp.com/getSpecCountries

This retrieves me my data from my MongoDB mLab database in JSON format and I was able to use it just fine in Qlik Sense to create visualizations. However, I can't connect to this API in Tableau Desktop and haven't found any helpful guides on the internet. I just want to retrieve this data and use it in my Tableau Desktop visualizations.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have described our way connecting to data in MongoDB Community Edition to Tableau, here is the detailed description how we did it: https://medium.com/@katya.neulinger/tableau-web-data-connector-to-mongodb-c1477d7d5ac9
Maybe it can be helpful for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tableau implemented a '[Web Data Connector](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/examples_web_data_connector.htm)' in version 9 which might be a good route for you. It requires that you write some code (JavaScript, I believe) in order to create your own Web Data Connector to bring in your JSON data.

Here is a [great resource](https://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2015/8/connect-just-about-any-web-data-new-web-data-connector-42246) to start your search. Here is a link to the [WDC community](https://community.tableau.com/community/developers/web-data-connectors?_fsi=iFGOd3nd). There are plenty of [examples](http://tableau.github.io/webdataconnector/community/) and even a code simulator.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I figured it out using the guidelines.

Comment: Excellent news!